# Добавление java бибилиотеки в Android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

Пытаюсь в проект для Android Studio добавить эту библиотеку: https://github.com/kochedykov/jlibmodbus

Примеры импорта, которые я находил для случаев, когда в импортируемом проекте есть gradle файл. Пробовал добавлять файл типа

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version '1.0'

dependencies {

}
```

Но классы из модуля не появляются в проекте. Подскажите, как правильно настроить сборку?

[image: Gradle файл отсутствует]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставьте в `build.gradle` в блок `dependencies` в папке `app` код из `readme` либы в

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.kochedykov</groupId>
  <artifactId>jlibmodbus</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Студия автоматически преобразует его в вид `compile 'com.github.kochedykov:jlibmodbus:1.2.8.4'`. Теперь можно синхронизировать проект и либа будет подключена.

Comment: В таком случае он подгружается из удаленного репозитория? И у меня на компьютере не хранится?

Comment: @levWi, так либа будет скачена на локальную машину из удалённого репозитория. Т.е. верно 1-ое, но не второе.

Answer (score 0):

В центральном репозитории уже есть версия 1.2.9.1.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intelligt.modbus</groupId>
<artifactId>jlibmodbus</artifactId>
<version>1.2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

С версии 1.2.9.0 пакет com.invertor.modbus сменился на com.intelligt.modbus.jlibmodbus.

Comment: Центральный репозиторий на github находится ?

Comment: На частном сервере.